# Textarea embedded in Iframe Becomes Uneditable with designMode = On

Tags: javascript, iframe, textarea, text-editor

As you can see, below I have two functions that are intended to make text bold: **doRichEditCommand()**, and **SetToBold()**.

My goal is, first, to get **doRichEditCommand()** to work in the *textarea* embedded in the `iframe` because it works on all major browsers flawlessly, and then to get **execCommand** functions like **SetToBold()** to work, because I'm unsure of them being cross-browser when in an *iframe*.

For the first function to work, I've enabled **designMode**. However, with it enabled the *textarea* becomes uneditable.

How can I modify the below code so my functions will work within a `textarea` embedded in an `iframe`?

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function getIFrameDocument(aID){
// if contentDocument exists, W3C compliant (Mozilla)
if (document.getElementById(aID).contentDocument){
return document.getElementById(aID).contentDocument;
} else {
// IE
return document.frames[aID].document;
 }
}

function load(){
getIFrameDocument("editorWindow").designMode = "On";
}

function doRichEditCommand(aName, aArg){
getIFrameDocument('editorWindow').execCommand(aName,false, aArg);
document.getElementById('editorWindow').contentWindow.focus()
} 

function SetToBold () {
        document.execCommand ('bold', false, null);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="load()">
  <iframe id="editorWindow" src="you.php"></iframe>
  <button onclick="doRichEditCommand('bold')" style="font-weight:bold;">B</button>
  <button onclick="SetToBold();">Bold</button>
</body>
</html>
```

P.S. I haven't included "you.php" because it's just the necessary tags and a textarea.